# Selenium _webDriver not finding element through By.LinkText

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running some Acceptance tests (C#) with **Selenium webdriver** and have the following line of code:

```
var link = _webDriver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Manage Service"));
link.Click();
```

On the navigated page, this anchor is what I am trying to target:

```
<a onclick="doEdit(this, 73332)" href="javascript:void(0);">
    <span>Manage Service</span>
</a>
```

But the test is failing due to Selenium not being able to find that anchor tag. I was under the impression that Selenium is able to handle the above scenario.

I also tried `By.PartialLinkText()` but again not found!

Why isn't is finding the link?

Comment: Can u please check that its not under a frame / iframe?

Comment: Hi @VivekSingh. I just checked, definitely **not** inside a `frame/iframe`

Comment: have you tried instead with tagName finding under the `<span>` tag? Or also go for xpath

Comment: Nope haven't tried those yet, but shouldn't this work? I'm working in a massive application and don't fancy going everywhere, finding what the XPath is and then changing Selenium to target XPath instead. :(

Comment: can u provide a bit of html more, the ones preceeding the link text? were u able to get elements before it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it wasn't finding it was because the previous step was not working properly.

Here is what I have in my test:

```
When I navigate to the 'services' page for the 'organisation'
    And I log into the site as a OD editor and return to the page I was on
    And I click on the 'Manage Service' link
```

The loging into the site step wasn't given enough time. So I told it to wait 2 seconds and then move onto the next step.

```
Thens.WaitForSecond(2);
```

Now it finds it without any problems.

Thanks

Comment: If efficiency is a concern, I would recommend looking into implicit or explicit waits which are contained in the Selenium package